# Power Line Communication

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, coupling

I am using an emitter and a receiver circuit in order to communicate through the power line.
The receiver circuit I am using is shown at the figure below and it uses the LM567 tone decoder to decode the 100KHz signals sent by the emitter. These 100KHz signals are 1msec long.
[image]

The receiver is powered by an external 230 to 24V adapter.
The grounds GND_ANA and GND are connected.
[image]
I am connecting an oscilloscope at the test point and adjusting the R51 potentiometer in order to decode the 100KHz signals. The signal is decoded and the LED D6 is blinking accordingly.
The problem I am facing is that when I am removing the scope from the circuit board, the LED D6 remains ON (not blinking) even when I stop sending the signals from the emitter.
I have also noticed that (in the situation where the Receiver is disconnected from the AC line, the Receiver is powered by the 230 to 24V adapter, the Emitter is sending its signals and the scope is connected to the test point) when I am touching the Line (L) of the receiver, I can correctly see the emitted signals and the LED D6 blinking ...
I am thinking about a coupling issue somewhere but not sure …May you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

The ground clip of most oscilloscopes connects directly to the earth pin of the power plug.

When you have the scope connected the ground of your circuit is connected back to AC power ground.  When you disconnect that connection is removed and the only ground connection is via C28 to the neutral line.

That is a reasonable way to connect your circuit but it is not functioning correctly for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry I did not mentioned it, but the ground of C28 (GND_ANA) is also connected to the ground C12 (GND), from the output of the adapter. And I am still confused because I cannot explain why, when the AC line is disconnected and when I am touching the L line, I have the signal at the “Test Point”, is the signal comes through the adapter ?